# How to avoid duplicates in file uploads

Tags: javascript

I have the following function to upload files. It takes both single and multiple uploads.

When the files are selected, I do a foreach to rename the files to a unique name by simply  concatenating the uniqueID name to the the file index.

The problem is when files are uploaded more than once, the first uploaded file is overwritten. Previous uniqueID[0] file is overwritten by a new upload file index of [0].

How do can I work around this to avoid overwriting the already uploaded files  by starting, or  renaming index from the last created index.

```
const uniqueID = XhKsZ;

 startUpload(event) {
    this.loading = true;

    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;

    this.files = Array.from(event.target.files);


    let filesFiletered = _.range(this.files.length);

    if(filesFiletered.length > 0){
      _.each(filesFiletered, ((idx) => {

    /*${uniqueID}${idx} filename*/

    const filePath = `folder/${uniqueID}/${uniqueID}${idx}`;
  }));
}
```

A second function call overwrites the previous file uniqueID because the files range starts at 0 again `let filesFiletered = _.range(this.files.length);`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: So you are saying your unique id is not unique?

Comment: I will edit to make it better. A ```second``` function call overwrites the previous files.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. What has the array index to do with a unique id? Why not use a timestamp?

Comment: ```const filePath = `folder/${uniqueID}/${uniqueID}${idx}`;``` file naming should be `XhKsZ0`, `XhKsZ1`, `XhKsZ2` and so on...  ```When the files are selected, I do a foreach to rename the files to a uniqueID by simply concatenating the unique name to the the file index.```